# Making coordinates of an object center the same when the image is resized

Tags: opencv, image-processing

Suppose we have an image of the form 130x260 and a rectangle that surrounds some object on the image. We can devide this image so that every row and every column has 13 cells. Suppose that (i,j) is a coordinate of that rectangle, where i and j are integers from 0 to 12. Then we resize the image to 416x416 and divide 416 by 13 cells, so we make again the same thing, only with this resized image. What will be coordinate of the rectangle on this new resized image? How can we achieve for it to be (i,j) again? My code looks like this:

```
img = cv2.imread(filename)
img_scaled = cv2.resize(img, (416, 416), cv2.INTER_CUBIC)
```

How cv2.INTER_CUBIC works? Is there some way to solve the problem?

Comment: You're scaling the image linearly, so the coordinates scale by the same proportion. Interpolation method used to determine pixel colour is irrelevant to that.

Comment: newX=416*oldX/130; same way for y.